# How to cast a list of lists into ints?

Tags: python, list, foreach, casting, integer

I am not understanding a basic concept in Python (C guy) and could use a) an answer b) an explanation

```
def do_the_deed(srctxt, upperlower)
# srctxt = "XGID=-b----E-C---eE---c-e----B-:0:0:1:21:0:0:1:0:10"

    alpha_list = srctxt[5:31]

    # map chars to ascii
    # [45],[66],[45],[45]....
    ord_list = [map(ord, x) for x in alpha_list]

    count = 0
    # what I want to do but can not!!!
    ??? for y = int(x) in ord_list  ???
        if y <> 45                    # acs('-') == 45
            if upperlower = 'UPPER'
                if ((y>= 97) and (y<= 112)):  # uppercase 15 valid
                    count += y - 96
            if upperlower = 'LOWER'
                if ((y>=65) and (y<=80)):     # lower case 15 valid
                    count += y - 64
     return count
```

I assume there is a tidy way for me to do this

```
xval = [int(x) for x in ord_list[0]]
```

gives me the first value.

I can explicitly iterate through the range from 0 to 26 but this seems like wrong thinking.  I've been googling but I don't know the right terms to search for.  Iterator, Enumerate, Cast... C type terms aren't getting me the right answer.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: try `for y in [x[0] for x in ord_list]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, or exactly what your asking. Your first list comprehension is already strange, since it converts to a list of single-value integer lists. Why do you want to do that anyway? Why not simply do `ord_list = [ord(x) for x in alpha_list]`, then you can iterate directly over ord_list?

Comment: do you mean one value `xval = int(ord_list[0])` or list `xval =[int(x) for x in ord_list]` (without `[0]`)

Comment: Don't use `<>` for comparison, it's cryptic and deprecated. Use `!=` instead.

Comment: `ord_list` is list of integers so you don't need to use `int()`

Comment: @furas, no it's not, it's a list of lists of integers. I asked above why that is; seems like it should be a list of ints.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right - in my testing code I changed `map(ord,x)` into `ord(x)` automatically so I didn't pay attention on it.

Comment: What is `do_the_deed` supposed to do? It looks like you want to filter for all upper or all lower case letters then sum up ordinals with `A=1, B=2, etc...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from this line:

```
ord_list = [map(ord, x) for x in alpha_list]
```

You are making lists twice, one with the list comprehension (`[ ... for x in ...]`), and one more with `map`. So you end with a list of lists of code of characters when (I assume) you just want a list of integers:

- currently you have : `ord_list` is `[[45], [98], [45], ..., [66], [45]]`
- what you need is : `ord_list` is `[45, 98, 45, ..., 66, 45]`

You can get it with either `map(ord, alpha_list)` or `[ord(x) for x in alpha_list]`

So your code could be like:

```
...
alpha_list = srctxt[5:31]

# map chars to ascii
# [45],[66],[45],[45]....
ord_list = map(ord, alpha_list)  # or [ord(x) for x in alpha_list]

count = 0
# what I want to do but can not!!! now you can :-)
for y in ord_list:
    if y <> 45:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you often want to use dictionaries:

```
import string
def do_the_deed(srctxt, upperlower):
    chars = string.lowercase if upperlower == 'LOWER' else string.uppercase
    translate = dict(zip(chars, range(1,27)))
    return sum(translate.get(c, 0) for c in srctxt[5:31])
```